# Laravel unable to write in the directory on CentOs7

Tags: laravel

I created laravel project that work fine on my local windows pc. Once I upload to Centos7 server(via SSH), I have problem to upload image, Unable to write to then directory. (project files structure https://ibb.co/5MLcFtd)

```
  Unable to write in the "upload/register/picture."
```

Already tried:

```
  chown apache:apache -R /var/www/html/srp/upload
  chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/srp/upload
```

and

```
  chown apache:apache -R /var/www/html/srp/upload/register/picture
  chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/srp/upload/register/picture
```

This is upload code.

```
if(Request::hasFile('picture')){
        $file = Request::file('picture');
        if( in_array($file->getClientOriginalExtension(), $extension_picture) ){
            $new_name = str_random(10).".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move('upload/register/picture' , $new_name);
            $new->picture = "upload/register/picture/".$new_name;
        }
    }
```

Both not working. Much appreciated for all answers.

Comment: Is apache user also running web server?

Comment: Hi Autista_z, It's CentOs7, should be apache as this image https://ibb.co/t4zXYrx

Comment: `Unable to write in the "upload/register/picture."` is not a real error msg.  What is the error you see, exactly?  Is it from `storage/logs/laravel.log`, or Apache log?

Comment: Also, show us permissions on `upload/` and subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

I think ssh user you are using doesn't have permissions to write. In this case, you should either upload via `root` (connect with `ssh root@your_server`) user or give permission to write to a user you're connecting with. (to do this you'll need root user access anyway)

Comment: Hi Some Dev, ssh is root already. Btw, error happened during submit data to server.

Comment: Hard-drive could be full, permissions could be wrong. You need to give some more information. 
how does a `ls -al` look in upload directory. What user is webserver running as? The more info you give, the easier it is to debug.

Comment: Hi larsemil , I deleted upload folder and try again then it worked. Thanks for your guide.